# In VS Code, why does pressing the backtick key in a Markdown file result in two backtick characters surrounding the caret?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The recent update changed the way VS Code handles the backtick key press.  Before it would output one backtick, but now it outputs two with the cursor in the middle.  I want to disable this setting, but when I search the default settings for 'backtick', 'tick', etc., nothing comes up.  What setting is this?

[image: backtick]

Answer (score 6):

This is standard behaviour for Markdown in VS Code, where [backticks are for code spans](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#code-spans). See also the `autoclosingPairs` property in [VS Code's extensions/markdown-basics/language-configuration.json](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/markdown-basics/language-configuration.json).

You can disable quote auto-closing globally by putting the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
```

You can disable it for just Markdown with the following:

```json
"[markdown]": {
    "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never",
},
```

Note that that will also affect double-quotes.

This behaviour existed even prior to VS Code 1.80. I'm not sure why you're just observing this now.

Comment: Actually I'm like OP, I'm using VS Code almost every day (though not doing some markdown everyday) and I just noticed this behavior. For sure this is a new behavior for me (less than a month old). Your solution works well, thank you.

Comment: note: related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192414

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the answer is:

`"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "never"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to a configuration change in VS Code is to use `~~~` to start and end your fenced code block.  This will allow the single backtick--seen in the `~~~` to function as another form of emphasis which is usually used in pairs.  Handily, it is on the same key too!