# How to disable automatic pairing of triple backticks in VS Code in Markdown files while keeping other auto-pairings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, backticks, pairing, vs-code-settings

I've been enjoying the features of Visual Studio Code, but there's one specific behavior that has been counterproductive for me: the automatic pairing of triple backticks (```) in Markdown files.

To clarify, I'm not looking to disable all auto-pairings—just the triple backticks. Whenever I type a single backtick, VS Code automatically completes it with two additional backticks. This is time-consuming to remove manually each time and disrupts my workflow.

Here's an example of what happens:

[Markdown - VS Code - Triple Backticks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIlOk.png)

Is there a way to disable this feature? If not, could someone guide me on how to disable this behavior in my own settings?

[I've seen a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76660341/in-vs-code-why-does-pressing-the-backtick-key-in-a-markdown-file-result-in-two) but it doesn't address my specific need to disable only the triple backticks while keeping other auto-pairings intact.

I've also created [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192676) to address this, but I'm wondering if there's a workaround or setting that I've missed.

Is there a way to achieve this? If not, could someone guide me on how to modify this behavior in my settings?

---

I tried searching through the VS Code settings and keybinding options to find a way to disable the automatic pairing of triple backticks specifically, but found no such setting. I expected to find an option that allows me to turn off this particular auto-pairing while keeping others. What actually happens is that every time I type a single backtick, it auto-completes to triple backticks, which I then have to manually remove.

I've also created a GitHub issue to address this concern. Additionally, [I've commented on the commits in the VS Code repository where this feature was recently implemented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/703a75da38519117da44e2b0a3b56200db56d756#r126904740), but have yet to find a solution or workaround.

I was expecting to find an option within the VS Code settings that would allow me to disable the automatic pairing of triple backticks specifically, while keeping other auto-pairings active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code has added the `autoClosingPairs` api mentioned below.  I have updated and released (v0.6.0) of my extension, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax) It is now easy to disable backtick closing completions in markdown files.  Here is a demo from the extension README:

[image: demo of extension modifying the markdown auto closing pairs completion in markdown files]

Note that I removed completion for both single and triple backticks in the example.

---

You can also edit the language configuration file yourself.  The only problem is that if it is ever updated by the vscode team you will have to re-do your changes.

On a Windows system, the relevant file is located at:

```
C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-basics\language-configuration.json
```

Here is what the autoClosingPairs key/value looks like for a markdown file:

````json
  "autoClosingPairs": [
    {
      "open": "{",
      "close": "}"
    },
    {
      "open": "[",
      "close": "]"
    },
    {
      "open": "(",
      "close": ")"
    },
    {
      "open": "<",
      "close": ">",
      "notIn": [
        "string"
      ]
    },
    {
      "open": "`",       // consider deleting this as well
      "close": "`"
    },
    {
      "open": "```",    // delete this {} entry and save
      "close": "```"
    }
  ],
````

You might want to make a back-up of that file first.

I wrote an extension, [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax), which has a command to show the language configuration file of the active editor:

```
Custom Language Properties: Show language configuration for current editor
```

It will open the relevant file (and the editor tab context menu `Copy Path` has its full path).  In the editor which is opened you can edit and save the document.  A reload is necessary for the edited language configuration file to take effect.

And you will no longer get autoclosing of triple backticks.  But there is sone issue, if you type 3 backticks in a row now vscode considers the third bactick to be part of an autoclosingPair itself and adds a fourth backtick...arg @#$.

That can be solved by also deleting the

```
    {
      "open": "`",       // consider deleting this as well
      "close": "`"
    },
```

making sure you don't leave any hanging commas in the json file.

BTW, I hate the triple backtick completion too.

You should also upvote this issue: [LanguageConfiguration interface should expose autoClosingPairs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173738) which would also allow my extension and others to fix the problem easily.  In fact, this already works but since the api is still proposed so it cannot be published.  But in testing it works as expected.

Demo is in a markdown file.  Auto-closing works for `{}()[]<>` but not backticks because I excluded them in this extension's settings.

[image: demo in markdown file with backticks not being auto-closed]

Comment: Dear @Mark, thank you for your thoughtful suggestion. It appears that your workaround aligns with my current approach, reaffirming that it may indeed be the sole viable option at this juncture. I shall mark your answer as correct to acknowledge its utility. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You could [edit your VS Code installation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192676#issuecomment-1783762300) as described in [Kirlak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77379066/11107541), though I think that will cause VS Code to issue a corruption warning).

As for why happens, see [the language configuration for the builtin Markdown extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/markdown-basics/language-configuration.json). Related Pull-Request which added backticks to auto-closing-pairs: [Add `` ` `` as an autoClosingPair in markdown #184532](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/184532) (release milestone: June 2023 (1.80)). Quoting from the description:

> Fixes [#183489](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/183489)
>
> Will test this out to see if it's helpful or too annoying

```` ``` ```` is only declared for auto-closing-pairs, but not as a bracket or quote type (makes sense, because it isn't), so you can't use the `editor.language.brackets` setting, and the `editor.autoClosingBrackets` has no effect on it. What you'll need if you want to do this through user configuration (instead of building your own modified VS Code or using a different Markdown extension than the builtin one) probably falls into the category of [User settings for language configurations
#102574](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102574), which I think would allow you to override `autoClosingPairs`.

The change is reverted by PR https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/202290, which will be released in the January 2024 release (1.86).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's worth noting this wasn't an issue until a recent update. Given it was possible before, 'can't be done' is hard to accept. I hope this can be revisited in future updates or settings. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Thank you for your continued efforts to refine your answer. However, the information provided is already known to me and doesn't address my specific concern. For further context, you may refer to my comment on this topic: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/703a75da38519117da44e2b0a3b56200db56d756#r126904740. To clarify, I'm not looking to disable all auto-pairings—just the triple backticks.

Comment: @Webia1 I'm not suggesting that you find a way to disable them all. Overriding autoClosingPairs would allow you to define it to contain everything that's there by default except for the backticks.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply remove those lines from the JSON config to effectively revert the PR that added them: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/184532

The file is in the application install directory. For me this was in the following locations:

Win11: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-basics\language-configuration.json`

MacOS: `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/markdown-basics/language-configuration.json`

Just open the file and delete one or both of the following lines from the `"autoClosingPairs"` array to turn off this behaviour (for me it was around line 14 when I formatted the file):

````
{ "open": "`", "close": "`" },
{ "open": "```", "close": "```" }
````

Beware: these customizations will most likely get overridden whenever the VSCode updates so it's a temporary workaround at best until MS fixes the issue.